# Stanford CRFClassifier performance evaluation output

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf

I'm following this FAQ https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml for training my own classifier and I noticed that the performance evaluation output does not match the results (or at least not in the way I expect).
Specifically this section

`CRFClassifier tagged 16119 words in 1 documents at 13824.19 words per second.
         Entity P       R       F1      TP  FP  FN
       MYLABEL  1.0000  0.9961  0.9980  255 0   1
         Totals 1.0000  0.9961  0.9980  255 0   1`

I expect `TP` to be all instances where the predicted label matched the golden label, `FP` to be all instances where `MYLABEL` was predicted but the golden label was `O`, `FN` to be all instances where `O` was predicted but the golden was `MYLABEL`.

If I calculate those numbers myself from the output of the program, I get completely different numbers with no relation to what the program prints. I've tried this with various test files. 
I'm using `Stanford NER - v3.7.0 - 2016-10-31`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F1 scores are over entities not labels.

Example:

```
(Joe, PERSON) (Smith, PERSON) (went, O) (to, O) (Hawaii, LOCATION) (., O).
```

In this example there are two possible entities:

```
Joe Smith   PERSON
Hawaii      LOCATION
```

Entities are created by taking all adjacent tokens with the same label.  (Unless you use a more complicated BIO labeling scheme ; BIO schemes have tags like I-PERSON and B-PERSON to indicate whether a token is the beginning of an entity, etc...).

Comment: I understand this. My question is about the performance evaluation. Let's take a simple example - Joe is a boy. Let's say the predicted entities are (Joe, PERSON) (is, O) (a, O) (boy, PERSON). This should report 1 TP 1FP, right? That's not what I'm observing in the reported TP, FP, FN.

Comment: Yes so recall should be 100% and precision should be 50%.

Comment: What your output suggests is that there are 256 token sequences marked MYLABEL, and in 255 cases the labelling is correct?  What format is your data in?

Comment: So I think the part I'm missing is about how entities are marked as correct/wrong. If my classifier predicts (for your example) (Joe, PERSON) (Smith, O) (went, O) (to, O) (Hawaii, LOCATION) (., O). Is the entire entity Joe Smith reported as incorrectly classified?

Comment: Yes.  The correct answer is an entity "Joe Smith", whereas you predicted "Joe."  No partial credit.