# Stanford NLP Precision & Recall Calculation in CRFClassifier

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to reconcile the Precision & Recall scores output by the Stanford CRFClassifier with the results I get by manually assessing the stdout output.

I note from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940195/stanford-crfclassifier-performance-evaluation-output) that the results are calculated on an all-or-nothing basis for entities with no partial credit given for correct labels within an incorrectly labelled entity. However, when I try to calculate an all-or-nothing score from the output on this basis, my result is still reasonably different to the score output by the CRFClassifier.

When I calculate an all-or-nothing score from the output I get 0.6870 precision and 0.4520 recall. This is in contrast to average scores over 4 folds of 0.6090 precision and 0.3987 recall returned by the Classifier.

To manually calculate entity scores, I take the stdout output from the Classifier and iterate through each word. To get the number of relevant entities, I take any sequence of words with the same correct label and call that an entity. I check the returned label for each of these words and if any of them are a mismatch then the entity is marked as incorrectly labelled.

To get the number of returned entitites I iterate through the words and similarly group up sequences that have the same returned labels. This gives me the total number of relevant entities, the number of correctly labelled entities and the total number of returned entities, and I use these to calculate precision and recall on an entity basis.

Comparing the total number of entities in the .ann files (2,169) and the total number of relevant entities calculated above (2,146) suggests that this way of counting entities is reasonably accurate.

The problem is getting the precision and recall scores this way gives results that are not very close to what the Classifier returns. I am not considering Other labels in the calculation. Is there any other factors I should be considering when calculating the scores? Is there a way to have the Classifier output what it considers as entities to compare with what I have?